# Android SWIPE TAB : [JSR82] connect:Connection is not created

Tags: android, tabs, bluetooth, connection, swipe

I am getting this error only on Swipe TAB but works perfectly on all other mobile phones.

Android Version-4.1.2
It shows message: Failed- 712 - [JSR82] connect:Connection is not created (failed or aborted).
712 : is the IOException. Any idea what is the meaning of this JSR82 error??

I am trying to connect to a Bluetooth printer using the below code:

```
private void connect(final String deviceAddress) {
      // Dont proceed if the bluetooth adapter is not valid
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            return;
        } else {
            selectedDevice = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(deviceAddress);
        }
        // Cancel the dicovery if still going on
        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }
        if (mbtSocket != null) {
            try {
                mbtSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                getIntent().putExtra(ERROR, 706);
                getIntent().putExtra(ERROR_MSG, ex.getMessage());
//#ifndef REMOVE_DEBUG                
                logger.debug("ERROR - 706", ex.getMessage());
//#endif                
            }
            mbtSocket = null;
        }


    // Try to connect with the selected device,
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connecting to " +  selectedDevice.getAddress(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    // made the thread different as the connecting proceedure might break down the system
    Thread connectThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
           Intent intent = getIntent();
           try {
                try {

                    Method m = selectedDevice.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocket", new Class[]{int.class});
                    try {
                        mbtSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(selectedDevice, 1);
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        getIntent().putExtra(ERROR, 707);
                        getIntent().putExtra(ERROR_MSG, e.getMessage());
//#ifndef REMOVE_DEBUG                            
                            logger.debug("ERROR = 707");
//#endif                            
                        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                            getIntent().putExtra(ERROR, 708);
                            getIntent().putExtra(ERROR_MSG, e.getMessage());
//#ifndef REMOVE_DEBUG                            
                            logger.debug("ERROR = 708");
//#endif                            
                        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                            getIntent().putExtra(ERROR, 709);
                            getIntent().putExtra(ERROR_MSG, e.getMessage());
//#ifndef REMOVE_DEBUG                            
                            logger.debug("ERROR = 709");
//#endif                            
                        }
                    } catch (SecurityException e) {
                        getIntent().putExtra(ERROR, 710);
                        getIntent().putExtra(ERROR_MSG, e.getMessage());
//#ifndef REMOVE_DEBUG                        
                        logger.debug("ERROR = 710");
//#endif                        
                    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                        getIntent().putExtra(ERROR, 711);
                        getIntent().putExtra(ERROR_MSG, e.getMessage());
//#ifndef REMOVE_DEBUG                        
                        logger.debug("ERROR = 711");
//#endif                        
                    }
                    //mbtSocket = selectedDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(SPP_UUID);
                    ERROR_CODE = intent.getExtras().getInt(ERROR);
//#ifndef REMOVE_DEBUG                    
                    logger.debug("ERROR = ", ERROR_CODE);
//#endif                    
                    if (ERROR_CODE == 0) {
                        mbtSocket.connect();
//#ifndef REMOVE_DEBUG                        
                        logger.debug("@@BTWrapperActivity - ", "Connected to selectedDevice = " + (String) intent.getExtras().get(EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS));
//#endif
                        intent.putExtra("IS_CONNECTED", true);
                        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
                    } else {
                        intent.putExtra(ERROR, ERROR_CODE);
                        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, intent);
                    }

                } catch (**IOException ex) {
//#ifndef REMOVE_DEBUG                    
                    logger.debug("BLUETOOTH STATUS", "ERROR - 712 - " + ex.getMessage());
//#endif**                    
                    getIntent().putExtra(ERROR, 712);
                    getIntent().putExtra(ERROR_MSG, "Unable to Connect to the Printer.");
                    getIntent().putExtra("IS_CONNECTED", false);
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to connect to " + selectedDevice.getAddress(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    ex.printStackTrace();
//#ifndef REMOVE_DEBUG                
                    logger.debug("In BTWrapperActivity ", ex.getMessage());
//#endif            
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, intent);
                }finally{
                    BTWrapperActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        pd.show();
                    }
                  });
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
        connectThread.start();
//#ifndef REMOVE_DEBUG                            
        logger.debug("++++++++++++++++IN CONNECT BTWRAPPER DONE+++++++++++++++");
//#endif 
    }
```

Comment: Can you add full logcat?

Comment: @kpan: Hello,I am trying to achieve bluetooth connectivity between my iball 3G 7271 swipe tablet and an RN42 bluetooth chip and am getting the same error that you mentioned.Have you been able to solve this issue?

Comment: No, we gave up when we realised it(Swipe tab) does not support bluetooth printing.